# Visual Studio 2022 - Error loading Apple provisioning profiles

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin, maui

I'm developing my MAUI app and testing it on my iOS device via Visual Studio 2022 (Version 17.7.6 on Windows). But suddenly I've lost my sync with my developer apple account. I've tried on other Windows PC on the same network and It works properly, but on my device, when adding my developer account I get this log error:

*There was an error while syncing the syncing identities information, please check the logs.*

*Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.AppleProvisioningManager Error: 0 : System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.*

Xamarin
Visual Studio

I've tried updating visual studio network and tried other device same network.
Also I've tried deleting and adding my account

Comment: The error indicates that the certificate has expired. Have you tried to create a new one,see:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/device-provisioning/manual-provisioning?tabs=vs

Comment: Nope, my certificates are on date. It seems there is problem on my machine because I've tried on other machine, same network and everything works perfect

Comment: I think there is an issue with the SSL/TLS certificate validation when trying to connect to Apple's servers. You can try to trust the Certificate and clear SSL Certificate Cache: On macOS, open Keychain Access, select the "System" keychain, and delete any outdated or problematic certificates;On Windows, open the "Internet Options" in the Control Panel, go to the "Content" tab, and click the "Clear SSL state" button.

Comment: Yes, I think It must be an error with the SSL certificate, but tried Clear SSL state, but It didn't work

Comment: Also please help check if the network firewall would cause this request to be blocked.

Comment: Firewall its OK. Tried another machine, same configuration and same network, and It works perfect (there are enterprise windows laptop with same configuration).

Comment: Thanks for the response, you can report a problem with VS, see [Report a problem with Visual Studio - Visual Studio (Windows) | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2022)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else having this issue and the error reported as "The specified network password is not correct" on Windows. Go to %LOCALAPPDATA%\Xamarin\iOS\Provisioning\Certificates rename the folder to something else and create an empty Certificates folder.

Via Visual Studio you should now be able to View Details of Apple Developer Accounts and create a new provisioning certificate.